# Server Exception occurs in running sbt project in IntelliJ

Tags: mongodb, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-14

I am starting to learn scala and running the application with IntelliJ IDE. I am now trouble in running the project with the following **ServerException**.
I would like to explain briefly about my project. I would like to connect to mongoDb from Scala application and I use scala version 2.10.0 and JDK 8.

This is my **build.sbt**

```
name := "MongoDbandScala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.6.0",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.4"
)
scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
```

This is **Common.scala**

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._

case class Stock (symbol: String, price: Double)

object Common {
  def buildMongoDbObject(stock: Stock): MongoDBObject = {
    val builder = MongoDBObject.newBuilder
    builder += "symbol" -> stock.symbol
    builder += "price" -> stock.price
    builder.result
  }
}
```

This is **MongoFactory.scala**

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoConnection

object MongoFactory {

  private val SERVER = "localhost"
  private val PORT = 27017
  private val DATABASE = "portfolio"
  private val COLLECTION = "stocks"
  val connection = MongoConnection(SERVER)
  val collection = connection(DATABASE)(COLLECTION)

}
```

This is my **Insert.scala** and cannot run till now.

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import Common._

object Insert extends App {
  // create some Stock instances
  val apple = Stock("AAPL", 600)
  val google = Stock("GOOG", 650)
  val netflix = Stock("NFLX", 60)
  // save them to the mongodb database
  saveStock(apple)
  saveStock(google)
  saveStock(netflix)

  // our 'save' method
  def saveStock(stock: Stock) {
    val mongoObj = buildMongoDbObject(stock)
    MongoFactory.collection.save(mongoObj)
  }
}
```

Now I am in trouble with the following exception. Can anyone mention the answer for my question?

```
> Error:scalac: Error:
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
    > 
    > Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.10.0-52.0'
    > 
    >   at
    > sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:145)
    > 
    >   at
    > sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
    > 
    >   at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:291)
    > 
    >   at
    > sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
    > 
    >   at
    > sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
    > 
    >   at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:291)
    > 
    >   at
    > sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
    > 
    >   at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInterfaceJar(IncrementalCompiler.scala:52)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:96)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:50)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:49)
    > 
    >   at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:49)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:22)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache$$anonfun$getOrUpdate$2.apply(Cache.scala:20)
    > 
    >   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:19)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:23)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:22)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:68)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:25)
    > 
    >   at
    > org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    > 
    >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    > 
    >   at
    > sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    > 
    >   at
    > sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    > 
    >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    > 
    >   at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

Comment: There was compatibility issues in earlier versions of Scala 2.10 and Java 8. If you have to use Scala 2.10, try 2.10.6. 
Another option is to use JDK 1.7 or JDK 1.6 to run Scala Compile Server, but I'm not sure if it is there in IDEA 14.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scala-compile-server.html

Comment: Thank you niktrop. I am running in sbt, not in IDEA 14. I already degraded my JDK to 1.7 but it doesn't work till now.